# how load image from sqlite database into android view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to load image from SQLite DB in my android app and set its values into a image slider (viewpager) similar this tutorial :

http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/12/android-image-slider-using-viewpager-example.html#comment-49936

please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to save your images in database in form of `byte[]` and then retrieve one by one in your pager adapter then convert `byte[]` to `Bitmap` and set in `ImageView`. But this is **not a good practice**.

If your images are static then you should store them in `drawables` as shown in that tutorial and if your images are dynamic and fetched from network you should **use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/) or any such library** to load those images directly from network into your `ImageView`.

This [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library/) might help you in integrating Picasso library.